# como puedo hacer para que el menu del navbar se habra de forma vertical y no horizontal? Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

tengo un navbar basico de bootstrap 4... que al acceder con dispositivos mobiles el menu del navbar se habre desde hacia arriba.. como puedo hacer que el menu se habra de forma vertical y asi tenga una aspecto mas nativo de dispositivos mobiles?

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-sm-start fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/puntajes')}}">Carsanies</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          {{ Auth::user()->USUARIO }}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mi numero de cuenta: {{ Auth::user()->id }}</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ Auth::user()->USUARIO }}</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('/cambiar_contrasena')}}">Cambiar Contraseña</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url('/logout') }}">Salir</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con "*de forma vertical*"

Comment: Creo que te refieres a un _sidebar_. Aunque Bootstrap hasta la fecha no tenga ese componente nativo, podemos hacerlo con CSS y jQuery

Comment: La verdad ni siquiera es muy necesario jQuery, yo sugeria evitarlo, aunque bien, si ya de por si se esta utilizando Bootstrap jQuery esta bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamentablemente hasta la fecha Bootstrap no ofrece algun componente que puedas utilizar de manera sencilla como un *sidebar*; si bien podrias modificar elementos para esto, yo te recomendaria crear tu propia estructura para manejar una sidebar hecha desde 0, y luego puedes utilizar los componentes de Bootstrap dentro de esa estructura sin problemas.

Asi te evitaras hacerle muchas alteraciones a los estilos de Bootstrap y sus componentes; aqui un ejemplo bastante sencillo de una sidebar que empuja el contenido para ocupar el espacio

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('hidden')
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar.hidden {
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar hidden">
    <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
      <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content p-5">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <button id="toggle" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```